# Environment for listing personal information or similar data

Tags: lists, environments, typography

Following good typography, what is the proper environment or LaTeX code for displaying this kind of list?

> Name:
>
> Telephone:
>
> E-mail:
>
> Web site:

The description environment never seems to look right for this kind of situation, especially when I have many such lists appearing within a document. Is there a special environment recommended for this kind of information?

Note, I am not necessarily referring to data appearing in in the front-matter. This can be information within the document and need not necessarily be presenting information about the author of the document.

Comment: You could put the data in a tabular. That allows you to right-align the first column and left-align the second. Makes it look a little better in my opinion.

Comment: I would use a tabular too, but with two left aligned columns, e.g. `\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}` or `\begin{tabularx}{@{}l>{\raggedright}X@{}}` (use `\tabularnewline` in this case).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments the simplest would be to a tabular environment similar to the solutions from [Align columns of text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34598/align-colums-of-text/34599#34599) and use tabular to align the columns, or [the `tabbing` environment](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/Tabbing).

[image]

If there is a lot of data you should consider using more than just one column.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{l@{\thinspace}l}
Name:      &Village\\
Telephone: &+12 111 111\\
E-mail:    &village@something.com\\
Web site:  &http://tex.stackexchange.com
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
If there is a lot of data consider two columns:

\medskip
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{l@{\thinspace}ll@{\thinspace}l}
Name:       &Village         &Email:    &village@something.com\\
Mobile:     &+12 111 111 111 &Website:  &http://tex.stackexchange.com\\
Phone:      &+12 111 111     &Birthdate:&04/01/1977
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

---

As per @Werner's comment, it would be useful to define as macro so that the formatting is consistent.  This is especially important if you are typesetting this more than once in a document.  I have also used `\url` here as per @YiannisLazarides suggestion, along with [the `hyperref` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/) to provide  click able link.  You could also just use [the `url` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/url/).

This version also uses [the `collcell` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/collcell) to provide the flexibility of selecting if the colon's are to be aligned using the `A` column type, or placed on the left using the `L` column type. This might be overkill for the case where you only have 4 entries, and could manually include the `:` in the `\UserInfo` macro at the appropriate points).  But if the list of entries grows longer this method allows you to easily switch between the two formats, should you later decide you like one version over the other.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{collcell}

\newcommand{\AddColon}[1]{#1:}%
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\collectcell\AddColon}{l}<{\endcollectcell}@{\thinspace}}% if want colons on left
\newcolumntype{A}{l@{:\thinspace}}% if want colons aligned

\newcommand{\UserInfo}[5][L]{%  #1 can be A=aligned colon, L=left colon
    \par\noindent%
    \begin{tabular}{#1 l}%
        Name      &#2\\%
        Telephone &#3\\%
        E-mail    &#4\\%
        Web site  &\url{#5}%
    \end{tabular}%
    \ignorespaces\par%
}

\begin{document}
\UserInfo{Village}{+12 111 111}{village@something.com}{http://tex.stackexchange.com}
\bigskip
\UserInfo[A]{Village}{+12 111 111}{village@something.com}{http://tex.stackexchange.com}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For the sake of consistency, I would suggest writing a macro that takes the personal information as arguments. Something like `\info{<name>}{<telephone>}{<email>}{<website>}`.

Comment: @Werner: Good point. I have updated the solution to include that.

Comment: @PeterGrill add this and you have a db also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15330/adding-a-list-of-bios-to-the-book-class/15338#15338 and a top solution. I would also user `\url` :)

Comment: @Peter Grill : you forgot to use the arguments #1, #2, #3 and #4 in the definition of the macro.

Comment: @projetmbc: Wow that's embarrassing. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Peter, would you really place the colon that far away from the corresponding word? In my opinion this looks really out of place, and the connection between the colon and the corresponding word is lost. Would it not make more sense to have the alignment as proposed by you, but then with the colon right after, for example, "Name:"? If not, why?

Comment: @tehingo: Have updated solution to provide an option to select between the two. I agree with you in that left aligned colon is probably better, just that in a previous question a user wanted the colons aligned so it didn't occur to me... Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 6):

Just to show some variations, here is a key-value approach:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{keyval,booktabs}

\makeatletter
\def\ui@key#1{\define@key{ui}{#1}{\@namedef{ui@#1}{##1}}}
\ui@key{name}\ui@key{place}\ui@key{phone}\ui@key{mobile}
\ui@key{email}\ui@key{website}\ui@key{style}

\def\ui@style@one{\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{ }l@{}}
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{Name: \ui@name} \\
  \midrule
  Place:   & \ui@place \\
  Mobile:  & \ui@mobile \\
  Phone:   & \ui@phone \\
  E-Mail:  & \texttt{\ui@email} \\
  Web site:& \texttt{\ui@website} \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}}
\def\ui@style@two{\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{ }l@{\qquad}l@{ }l@{}}
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{4}{@{}l@{}}{Name: \ui@name} \\
  \midrule
  Place:   & \ui@place     & E-Mail:    & \texttt{\ui@email} \\
  Mobile: & \ui@mobile   & Web site:  & \texttt{\ui@website} \\
  Phone:  & \ui@phone    & & \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}}

\newcommand{\UserInfo}[1]{%
  \setkeys{ui}{style=one,name=,place=,mobile=,phone=,email=,website=,#1}%
  \@nameuse{ui@style@\ui@style}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\UserInfo{%style=one, % default
  name=Brutus L. User,
  place=Village,
  mobile=+12 111 111 111,
  phone=+12 111 111,
  email=village@something.com,
  website=http://tex.stackexchange.com}

\bigskip

\UserInfo{style=two,
  name=Brutus L. User,
  place=Village,
  mobile=+12 111 111 111,
  phone=+12 111 111,
  email=village@something.com,
  website=http://tex.stackexchange.com}


\end{document}
```

One can choose between one an two column tabular. The `\ui@key` macro is just to avoid repeating over and over similar definitions such as

```
\define@key{ui}{name}{\def\ui@name{#1}}
```

[image]

Comment: Hope you don't mind me asking an unrelated question, is it possible to pass values from one family to another with keyval, i.e., if you had a key width for example in one family to pass it onto an includegraphics?

Comment: @YiannisLazarides I think that **xkeyval** says something about this.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: With `xkeyval` you can give multiple families which a tried one by one, and you can use `\setkeys*` to store all unknown keys in a macro which can be processed later. I'm using this in `adjustbox` for example.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Thanks you you guys are right I had a look at the xkeyval docs and its all there.